# Azure Devops ( ADO) - How can I report on team member capacity over time?

Tags: azure-devops, reporting, agile

In ADO I am trying to track my team members capacity per sprint compared to actual work completed (in hours against tasks).

I can't find any way to export that field using queries or analytics.

Can anyone help?

I have tried queries and analytics but past capacity doesn't seem to be available